# Linking TagLib to my Qt app on Windows?

Tags: windows, qt, taglib

I compiled taglib.dll using there instructions:
http://www.joelverhagen.com/blog/2010/11/how-to-compile-taglib-on-windows/

I now try to link it with my application using the following options:
win32:LIBS += -L"./resources/win" -ltag

ld.exe fails saying -ltag cannot be found. I've tried this with -L"C:/absolute/path" -ltag and a number of other ways but always the same. The taglib.dll file is located in ./resources/win/... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Pfff... The working line is simply: "LIBS += resources/win/taglib.dll". Oh well...